# MS Access 2010 VBA SQL error 3122

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I am hitting a snag in my SQL and I can't seem to figure out the solution.  I have isolated the part of the code causing the error, but I can't seem to fix it.  The issue is in the `(TimeValue([tblDeptTime]![DeptTime]) BETWEEN (TimeValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time]) - [tblDeptWindowsLeadTimes]![NBLT]) AND TimeValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time])` portion of my `SQLHaving` statement.

The error states that I am trying to execute a query that does not include the specified expression `[Schedule Name])=[Forms]![frmStationReports]![cbxSchedName]) AND (([tblAllSchedules]![Arvl Sta])=[Forms]![frmStationReports]![cbxArvlSta]) AND DateValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time]) >= #" & FMon & "# AND DateValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time]) <= #" & LSun & "#) AND ((tblAllSchedules.Type)='NB'`  This is the first part of my `SQLHaving` statement.

Here is the entire SQL code.  Thanks for your assistance.

```
SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO tblDeptWindowNB ( [Schedule Name], [Arvl Sta], [Day], [Date], Metal, Type, [Key ID], [LAA NB], [LUS NB], [Sub Fleet], CompSchedName, CompSchedDay, DeptTime ) "
    SQLSelect = "SELECT [Schedule Name], [Arvl Sta], Format(DateValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time]),'ddd') AS [Day], DateValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time]) AS [Date], Metal, Type, [Key ID], [LAA NB], [LUS NB], [Sub Fleet], '" & csName & "', Sum(DateDiff('d', '" & FMon & "' ,  [tblAllSchedules]![MX In Date/Time])+ 1) AS CompSchedDay, [tblDeptTime]![DeptTime] "
    SQLFrom = "FROM tblDeptTime, tblAllSchedules, tblDeptWindowsLeadTimes "
    SQLGroup = "GROUP BY [Schedule Name], [Arvl Sta], DateValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time]), [tblDeptTime]![DeptTime], Metal, Type, [Key ID], [LAA NB], [LUS NB], [Sub Fleet] "
    SQLHaving = "HAVING ((([tblAllSchedules]![Schedule Name])=[Forms]![frmStationReports]![cbxSchedName]) AND (([tblAllSchedules]![Arvl Sta])=[Forms]![frmStationReports]![cbxArvlSta]) AND DateValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time]) >= #" & FMon & "# AND DateValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time]) <= #" & LSun & "#) AND ((tblAllSchedules.Type)='NB') AND (TimeValue([tblDeptTime]![DeptTime]) BETWEEN (TimeValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time]) - [tblDeptWindowsLeadTimes]![NBLT]) AND TimeValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time]))"
    SQLOrderBy = "ORDER BY [Schedule Name], [Arvl Sta], DateValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time])"

    SQLStatement = SQLInsert & SQLSelect & SQLFrom & SQLGroup & SQLHaving & SQLOrderBy & ";"

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQLStatement
```

Comment: Do you simply need a space at the end of your HAVING line?

Comment: lol, I wish.  I must have deleted when I did my last edit, but it is in there now and still has the same error.

Comment: Have you tried running it directly in SQL? Usually when I run into an issue like this it is because I forgot to include a column in my select list.

Comment: Are you really doing a cross join through all those tables? Do none of the table relate with join keys?

Comment: I only have MS Access and it still gives me the same answer.  But I will double check my columns.

Comment: One table has all my data in it, and the other two tables only contain parameter data.

Comment: I double checked, and my Insert and select columns add up.

Comment: The field `[tblDeptWindowsLeadTimes]![NBLT]` is not included in `GROUP BY`. Overall, this is hard to debug without data. If you remove `HAVING` does query run? If so, try adding each clause one by one and check.

Comment: I added it, and still have the same issue. I already added the Having one clause at a time, which is how I know it has something to do with the `(TimeValue([tblDeptTime]![DeptTime]) BETWEEN (TimeValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time]) -  statement.

Comment: and, yes it runs without the having statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I needed to move the `(TimeValue([tblDeptTime]![DeptTime]) BETWEEN (TimeValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time]) - [tblDeptWindowsLeadTimes]![NBLT]) AND TimeValue([tblAllSchedules]![MX Out Date/Time])` statement into a `Where` statement and now it works perfectly.  Thanks guys.